# How to create a JS toggle (UP/DOWN) header?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to create this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxx9g.png]

I have tried it from other examples on JSFiddle but it's not what I want or what I was expecting.

I feel this would need to be created in JS also by using css, also by implementing a cookie. I would be using this as a header for showing SSI examples from a PHP query linked from my forum to my main website.

```
<p id="welcome"><?php ssi_welcome(); ?></p>
```

CSS:

```
#welcome {
background: #ccc;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-family: calibri;
font-size: 15px;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 16px;
text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuerys slideToggle function.

Some thing like this:

```
$( '#button-to-toggle-area' ).click( function( e ) {

    $( '#area-to-show-or-hide' ).slideToggle( 'fast' );
    e.preventDefault();
});
```